# Flexible and fast container at runtime

Tags: c++, stl

I need a fixed size (fast) container like `std::array` to store user input like this

User input:

```
n = {2,3,2,1}
```

Generated output (at runtime):

```
m = {{2x3},{3x2},{2x1}}
```

How to archive a fast access to `m`? A normal `std::vector` seems to be too slow.

Comment: _"... seems to be too slow."_ What did you measure under which exact circumstances? You may use an already resized `std::vector<>`.

Comment: Consider that your program logic will be a gazillion times faster than user input and also compared to the final output. Let's say a billion times faster, just to take a number, although that's far too small a number. Why do you want it yet faster?

Comment: Why does `std::vector` seem so slow to you?

Comment: and what's wrong with `std::array`?

Comment: Wait... access time to vector is slow? Access? There is a marginal if any at all overhead at accessing vector compared to a plain array. To get anything faster than than you would need to go into engineering, like cache management and stuff.

Comment: It's just an example above. n is much bigger and m is iterated 10⁶ or 10⁷ times. A non-fixed-sized container seems to me a bit slower than a fixed-sized. In this form, m can't be an array as I understand due to different sizes of the sub-arrays and furthermore n is unknown until runtime.

Comment: _"A non-fixed-sized container seems to me a bit slower"_ - Build each approach in release mode, profile with a suitable test, post the results proving the vector is insufficient - otherwise it didn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

Since you explicitly ask for **fixed size**, `std::array` is indeed what you want. While the size is constant, the contents are not, so you can write user input into a `std::array` just fine.

**However**, it is not certain that what you want is what you *should be wanting*. Feeding user input into a fixed-size container is an utterly bad idea, and the effective extra overhead of vector is one memory allocation (and a free operation), which hardly matters for something that happens just once at program start.
`std::vector` will mean a neglegible, ridiculously small extra overhead for the initial allocation, but it gives the guarantee that no matter how much data the user submits, you can always push it without having a buffer overflow. That is a huge thing for a very acceptable cost.

Accessing elements in both `std::array` and `std::vector` is as fast as it can get provided that you use `operator[]` (the `at` member function checks bounds!) and provided that you do not compile in debug mode or with any such thing as a "memory sanitizer" option that e.g. LLVM provides.

Debug mode and sanitizer functions obviously *do add overhead*, but that's widely irrelevant for the release binary that you will ship, and after all it's what you ask for, too.

Besides, statements like *"seems to be slow"* are almost guaranteed to give you negative responses. Never guess what *may* be slow (measure, don't guess), and don't do that prematurely anyway.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector seems to be the thing since it's based on array. Consider two things:

- use [] access instead of at() (but be sure to provide correct index);
- prepare your vector with vec.resize(expectedSize) to reduce (or exclude at all) resizing overhead.